Fixing lumbar support - Lincoln Town Car
My lumbar support stopped working on me and I'm wondering if I can try to fix it myself.  I have had spinal fusions and need another one, so it's pretty important to me.  I'm kind of a girly girl and don't know much about it about fixing stuff  lol
This is an '05 Lincoln Town Car Signature.  When I push the button for the lumbar support (driver's seat), I can still hear the motor so it's trying to do it's thing.  I attached a photo taken from the backseat of the underneath, in case that's helpful at all.  Any and all help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!!


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It'd be fixable, but it'd be hard to tell you what would be involved. Since the motor runs, it means the wiring/motor are working. What you're showing under the seat isn't going to be of much help. The guts of the lumbar support are completely in the back of the seat. The motor pulls the top and bottom of the support together, which causes it to pooch out. You'd have to take the back seat cover off to tell what's going on, which can be quite a chore. You might consider just getting a used replacement seat, which would be pretty easy to change out.
